# Can $1!+2!+3!+\cdots n!$ be a perfect number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, perfect-numbers

Can $\sum_{k=1}^nk!$ be a perfect number?

I think an odd perfect number can be divisible by $9$ and the last digit of an odd perfect number can be $3$, so I think the above sum can be a perfect number.

Am I correct?

Comment: Would recommend that you use mathjax for your equations. You can surround your latex code with "$$" on both sides, and the rendering will look better. People are more drawn to answer questions if they look more professional

Comment: If you are right, you won't find out here, because whether odd perfect numers even exist is an unsolved problem.

Comment: @ZoeAllen A lot is known about necessary conditions for an odd integer to be perfect, so there _might_ be a proof with existing techniques that this sum isn't.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque I'm not sure about this question falling to the side of elementary number theory. When the site was in its infancy somebody told me that the line is roughly at the level of quadratic reciprocity. Joffan's answer is in a sense elementary, but it does rely on basic properties of odd perfect numbers. May be it is just my limited exposure, but I would rank odd perfect numbers above quadratic reciprocity? No argument really, I simply would like to hear a bit more about where you draw the line. If you find the time to explain, that is :-) The line is fuzzy anyway.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The result used below has a simple proof and occurs in many elementary number theory textbooks (probably also here too). Likely it occurs in more older textbooks since research on this ancient recreational topic has waned in modern times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, such numbers cannot be perfect numbers. From the 22nd term onwards, the sum is divisible by $11$ but not by $121$, and odd perfect numbers need to have all prime factors $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ with even exponents.